# How to ensure that file has been deleted from folder and also related data deleted from database in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working with codeigniter, i want to delete a file from a folder and also delete related data from database. But how to ensure that either both will be done successfully otherwise none of them will took place.

Following code is my approach towards it, but i am concern about the case like, file deleted successfully but for some reason database operation was unsuccessful. Is there any better approach for this?

```
if(unlink($path)){
    $this->admin_model->delete_data($id,$db);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry with my answers, but with my exp to work with CI for 5 months. I'll use this method:
First, function delete_data($id,$db) must be return an effective_rows like:

```
public function delete_data($id,$db)
{
  // your code delete
  return $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```

Then edit a little bit of your code:

```
if($this->admin_model->delete_data($id,$db) > 0)
{
  if(unlink($path)) {
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

Hope it help. Sorry about my bad english.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it was helpful.

Comment: Well your code ensures that unlink() will not take place if data deletion were not successful.... but what if data deletion was successful then for some reason unlink() does not work?? My question was how to ensure that either both will took place or none of them.

Comment: Ah i see, if that you can use `if(unlink($path) && $this->admin_model->delete_data($id,$db) > 0)` to confirm 2 of them. So if not you can search 'rollback mysql' if unlink not working.

Comment: Thank you for your help.